# Slicing a list from the end

Tags: python, list, slice

Say, I have a list of values:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How can I make it include the end value through slicing? I expected:

```
>>> a[4:]
[4]
```

instead of:

```
>>> a[4:]
[]
```

Comment: List indices are zero based in Python.

Comment: It's `[3:]`, not `[4:]`. Try it with a list of characters instead of numbers.

Comment: If you just want the last value use `a[-1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slicing indices start from zero

So if you have:

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
          |  |  |  |
          V  V  V  V
          0  1  2  3   <-- index in xs
```

And you slice from `4` onwards you get:

```
>>> xs[4:]
[]
```

*Four is is the length of ``xs`, not the last index!*

However if you slice from `3` onwards (*the last index of the list*):

```
>>> xs[3:]
[4]
```

See: [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Many many common computer programmming langauges and software systems are in fact zero-based so please have a read of [Zero-based Numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)

Answer (score 1):

Python indexes are *zero based*. The last element is at index 3, not 4:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[3:]
[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a[-1:]
```

In python you can iterate values from beginning to end ending to beginning
 1, 2, 3, 4

|  |  |  |

0  1  2  3 (or)

-4 -3 -2 -1

So If you want last element of the list you can use either a[len(a)-1:] or a[-1:]